# UI Ribbon throws an OLE Exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Using facilities from Erik Van Bilsen (GitHub) to create a ribbon-style menu, and carefully following the instructions for incorporating a simple ribbon menu into a new VCL form application in Delphi 10.1, I run into an OLE exception (unspecified) when running my app.  The error happens at the line indicated below:

```
procedure TUIRibbon.Load();
Ribbon resource "%s": %s';
var
  Inst: THandle;
  lForm: TCustomForm;
begin
  if (Available) and (inherited Visible) and not (FLoaded) then
  begin
    // Load mapper for mapping between commands and VCL actions
    fRibbonMapper := TRibbonMarkupElementList.LookupListByResourceName(FResourceName);
    if (FResourceInstance = 0) then
      Inst := HInstance
    else
      Inst := FResourceInstance;
    try
      // OLE Exception.  Unspecified error happens here: 
      FFramework.LoadUI(Inst, PChar(FResourceName + '_RIBBON')); //Note:                       FResourceName = 'APPLICATION' here.   
      FLoaded := True;
      if Assigned(FOnLoaded) then
        FOnLoaded(Self);
      if roAutoPreserveState in Options then
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the latest version from https://github.com/TurboPack/RibbonFramework?  It appears that Erik has not been involved recently and there are numerous commits at the new repository, along with a pretty good tutorial in the wiki.

Comment: I took a look at that website.  Looks like I would need to get several source files and recompile.  I've decided to use a simpler approach.  I'm building a decent ribbon style menu piece by piece using familiar controls.  After all, I only need buttons and drop-down combos, none of the fancier controls like those used in Word or Excel.